# I made a icon for burg in ubuntu 12.04 but icon not shown

Tags: 12.04, icons, burg

I made a icon for burg in ubuntu 12.04 but icon not shown ??help
image format .png and i set to rgb with size 128x128 px in photoshop but it is'nt working in my burg,,can anyone tell me how to save image icon for burg !?

Comment: How did you make an icon?

Answer (score 0):

You application icon must be specified in the application .desktop file in the following two ways:

- Full path to file, for example: `/home/user/Pictures/icon.png`
- Name of icon installed in the theme, for example `icon` which points to the installed file `/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/128x128/apps/icon.png`

If your icon is not installed on the computer in the right place it will NOT appear from your desktop file and will not appear in Unity correctly. You may not use local paths such as `./icon.png` or `../icons/icon.png` but only a fully qualified name.

The icon can be in a few different formats. The popular format is SVG, followed by PNG and a few gimp pixmap formats for compatibility. Make sure your icon is in PNG format if it's raster, and SVG if it's vector.